Finding Quintic Formula using any possible set of functions
Let's say that we are able to create a finite set of functions. The functions can be either single-argument ones (for example Cosine) or two-argument ones (for example Sum). The fuctions can only accept numbers as arguments (not another functions for example). The functions can be both currently existing ones or totally new functions specially defined by us for this case (currently existing ones are strongly prefered though).
The question: would we be able to create such a set of functions that would allow us to create quintic formula (and possibly solving higher polynominals also) using its functions?
I heard that Abel–Ruffini theorem claims that just using basic operations and n-th roots isn't enough to create it but how about using any possible functions?
For example equation:
x*e^x = a

is not solvable normally however we created W function that does exactly that and we use it in many usecases even for much more complex problems. Maybe we could create such a magic function(s) for polynominals also?
I just ask for possibility in general, not the exact solution for the problem. Maybe someone proved already that it is impossible however I never found it exactly stated.
If it's impossible I will stop wasting time trying to find such a set :D
Please don't downvote if you find the question silly or wrong in some way, I'm still learning to use this site..
I am wondering about this problem since some time but my maths skills are sadly currently not enough to find the solution. Thank you in advance for the answer <3

There is a known method using "Bring radicals" , I have no idea whether your approach might work. In fact, the Abel-Ruffini theorem only applies to very special methods that definitive cannot work. For every additional degree however we will need more and more complicated methods , so that already degree $6$ is so complicated that it is best to solve it numerically.

I imagine, it is very complex. But I wonder that maybe there is some magic function that its usage would allow us to solve any polynominal

You can use Thomae’s formula or increasingly complicated hypergeometric functions, like this one apparently for the sextic.

This is an interesting question which does not have a clean yes or no answer.
If you allow "any possible set of functions" then the answer is "yes". For each degree, just use the function that has the polynomial's coefficients for input and outputs the set of roots of each input polynomial.
If you carefully specify what kinds of functions you allow the question becomes more interesting.
Here is one of the answers to a similar question at
this post on mathoverflow. It's pretty technical.

The answer to the first question is "yes". The Galois group of any
$$th degree polynomial is a subgroup of $S_n$. There are only a finite
number of these, and so for each such subgroup we can make a Bring
radical for it. Even more efficiently, we can make a Bring radical for
all finite simple groups which appear in the composition series for
one of these subgroups. Either way, we will get a finite set of Bring
radicals which can solve all $$ degree polynomials.


Thank you for the answer. It is indeed technical but at least something to check out.

About your comment, It was of course function that accepts numbers, not entire functions :D I will edit my question

@AmaeSaeki A polynomial of degree $n$ is determined by its $n+1$ complex coefficients, so a function of such a polynomial is just a function of that many complex values. See my edit.

Yes but as you see in my question, I limit the number of arguments to maximum 2. Regardless of the degree of the polynominal. For example, the foruma for 4th degree uses many third and second degree roots, multiplications and so on, even though the 4th degree polynominal has 5 complex coeficients.

@AmaeSaeki Then you can't even solve quadratics since the quadratic formula has three inputs.

The formula itsself can have many inputs yes, but the functions used in these forumals can have max two. We just build this large formula using functions with max two arguments. Regardless if we create formula for 5th degree or 20th degree

You are incrementally narrowing your definition in ways that I don't find particularly interesting. I've said about as much as I can to answer your question.
